# .htaccess RewriteRule conditionals?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to create two RewriteRules but cannot seem to get mod_rewrite to play nice.

What I am trying to achieve is the following...

`domain.com/my/friendly/url = domain.com/index.php?a=$1`

This one is simple enough, but I am trying to check for the existence of a number (of arbitrary length) to then add as a second request parameter.

For example

`domain.com/my/friendly/url/100 = domain.com/index.php?a=$1&id=$2`

Where `$1` is `my/friendly/url` and `$2` is `100`.

I've tried numerous patterns without success. My `.htaccess` file is left looking like this and is failing.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(\/[0-9]+)$ index.php?a=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?a=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your rules like this:

```
# ignore all rules for real files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?a=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Works a treat! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I noticed that the 2 RewriteCond were breaking the whole code, but I would like to understand **why**, as these RewriteRule were correct?

Comment: 1. Main problem was the regex used in OP's first `RewriteRule`. 2. `RewriteCond` is only applicable to next `RewriteRule` not to all the `RewriteRule`.

Comment: I see the problem with the first `RewriteRule` now. There was no distinction between the separating `/`?.